# vTiger webservice "ACCESS_DENIED : Permission to perform the operation is denied for id"

Tags: php, web-services, api, vtiger

I want to add SalesOrder through vTiger webservice. I'm using for this vtwsclib. Here is the code:

```
<?php
include_once('vtwsclib/Vtiger/WSClient.php');
$url = 'http://localhost:8888';
$client = new Vtiger_WSClient($url);
$login = $client->doLogin('admin', 'zzzzzzzz');
if(!$login) echo 'Login Failed';
else {

    $data = array(
        'subject' => 'Test SalesOrder',
        'sostatus' => 'Created',
        'invoicestatus'=>'AutoCreated',
        'account_id'=> '46', // Existing account id
        'bill_street' => 'Bill Street',
        'ship_street' => 'Ship Street',
    );
    $record = $client->doCreate('SalesOrder', $data);

$error = $client->lasterror();
    if($error) {
    echo $error['code'] . ' : ' . $error['message'];
}

if($record) {
    $salesorderid = $client->getRecordId($record['id']);
}

}
?>
```

And I get only: "ACCESS_DENIED : Permission to perform the operation is denied for id".

Account_id exists in database. Other SalesOrder was added with the same account_id but through webpage. I have also tried variant with accout_id = "6x46" where 6 is module_id. It also didn't work. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: is your salesorder table primary key has autoincrement behaviour? what is the name of primary key field in salesorder

Comment: It's accountid but when I change that in code I get other type of error, that field account_id is required.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should be trying 11x46 for account id. Vtiger web services entity id's are different from tabids.

To get a correct list of all entity ids, execute this in your MySQL for the CRM:

```
select id, name from vtiger_ws_entity;
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies in vtiger documentation.
add **entityName** parameter in GET request.

```
var q = "select * from Users;";
"http://vtigercrm/webservice.php?operation=query&sessionName=ABC&entityName=XYZ&query="+q
```

This worked well for me. Although still couldn't understand that by giving any entityName or garbage string, program works !!! Please comment if you know more about this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug in @Vtiger's web service.
You can change the file named `Create.php` as following:
(add the code between *)

```
    foreach ($referenceFields as $fieldName => $details) {
    if (isset($element[$fieldName]) && strlen($element[$fieldName]) > 0) {
        *if($fieldName == 'roleid' || $fieldName == 'currency_id'){
            continue;                    
       }*
        $ids = vtws_getIdComponents($element[$fieldName]);
        $elemTypeId = $ids[0];
        $elemId = $ids[1];                
        $referenceObject = VtigerWebserviceObject::fromId($adb, $elemTypeId);
        if (!in_array($referenceObject->getEntityName(), $details)) {
            throw new WebServiceException(WebServiceErrorCode::$REFERENCEINVALID,
                    "Invalid reference specified for $fieldName");
        }
        if ($referenceObject->getEntityName() == 'Users') {
            if(!$meta->hasAssignPrivilege($element[$fieldName])) {
                throw new WebServiceException(WebServiceErrorCode::$ACCESSDENIED, "Cannot assign record to the given user");
            }
        }
        if (!in_array($referenceObject->getEntityName(), $types['types']) && $referenceObject->getEntityName() != 'Users') {
            throw new WebServiceException(WebServiceErrorCode::$ACCESSDENIED,
                    "Permission to access reference type is denied" . $referenceObject->getEntityName());
        }
    } else if ($element[$fieldName] !== NULL) {
        unset($element[$fieldName]);
    }
}
```